# Will Swift 2.0 be compatible with OS X 10.9 or lower?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm currently working with Swift 2.0 beta, but read some documentation that says Availability OS X 10.10 or later - in simple NS class docs (which may just be Apple being careful).

Is it planned to be compatible for older versions?

Comment: Xcode 7 isn't supposed on 10.9 or earlier, so you'll be unable to use Swift if you want to suppose both 10.9, 10.10 and 10.11, as Swift 1.2 isn't available for 10.11 or later.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen, you are confusing the OSes that Xcode will run on with the OSes that the compiled applications will run on.  Yes, you need OS X 10.10 or later to run Xcode 7 and compile a Swift 2.0 app, but you can build that for a OS X 10.9 system.  Likewise, you can use Xcode 6.4 to build a Swift 1.2 app, and that will run on OS X 10.9, 10.10, and yes 10.11 systems.

Comment: @vacawama Usually Apple drops support for n-1 SDKs per Xcode version (at least for iOS). And while a app built for 10.9 will run on 10.11, you can't utilise the features of the 10.11. It's less about language, and more about the SDK availability.

Comment: Yes, you can't use 10.11 specific features with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4) because you need Xcode 7 which supports Swift 2.0 only.  But, you can use Xcode 7 to build apps for OS X 10.9 and above even though Xcode itself requires 10.10.X and above to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift's oldest supported deployment target is still OS X 10.9 and iOS 7. This is unchanged in Swift 2.

Certain APIs, however, are only available on later versions of these operating systems. I suspect this is what you mean by:

> documentation that says Availability OS X 10.10 or later - in simple NS class docs

(As Martin R. notes in the comments, this is unrelated to the language, except that "Swift has better runtime check mechanisms.")

With Swift 2, you can check API availability using the `#available` syntax. Here's an example from the [Xcode release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_6/Xcode_7_beta_6_Release_Notes.pdf):

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, OSX 10.10, *) {
    // Use Handoff APIs when available.
    let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType:"com.example.ShoppingList.view")
    activity.becomeCurrent()
} else {
    // Fall back when Handoff APIs not available.
}
```

Comment: It should perhaps be emphasized that the availability of a certain (Cocoa/Cocoa Touch/Foundation) *API* is completely unrelated to the *language* (Swift vs. Objective-C), only that Swift has better runtime check mechanisms.